# How to make a role from schema A "grantable" in schema B

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-grant

There are two schemas in the same database: A and B. Schema A has a role A_ROLE. I want to be able to give grants to A_ROLE from schema B ( so that the users with A_ROLE were able to query tables from schema B)

Is it possible?
If so, how does one do it?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, in Oracle the role is a non-schema object, so a schema can not own a role.

But if you mean that User A has a role A_ROLE and want give it grants to the objects from the schema B, then you can use the following statement as an example:

GRANT SELECT ON B.table1 TO A_ROLE;

Comment: But there is a one-to-one relationship between users and schemas in Oracle. So I guess when Dennis says "Schema A has a role" he actually means "User A has a role"

Comment: I have updated the answer corresponding to your comment.